# Can you lock the sorting order in Mail? (OSX 10.11)

Tags: macos, email

Just wondering if it's possible to lock the sorting order in Mail? My mom keeps accidentally clicking on the top bars "From, Date, Subject" and getting confused. I'd like to be able to lock it to only sort by date Descending but still display the "From, Date and Subject" tabs so she knows what she's looking at.

Comment: Would you mind attaching a screenshot? I'm not sure which "tabs" you're talking about.

Comment: The ones highlighted in green here: http://torquemod.com/MacMail.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I do that all the darn time - irritating, though I know what I did & can fix it quickly enough. Interested to see if there's a 'fix'.

Comment: I noticed when looking for a screen shot of the program online (my mom is sleeping and I'm on a PC) that some people don't even have the sorting options showing in Mail. At the least it would be nice to set it to Descending by Date and then turn off the bar all together but it'd be better to have the option to lock it while still leaving it visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an easy way to do this, so I wrote a Mail plugin for it. You can download it [here](https://github.com/saagarjha/MailHeaderLock/releases/tag/v1.0), and the source code is available [here](https://github.com/saagarjha/MailHeaderLock). I wrote it for macOS Sierra, so if it doesn't work on your mom's computer please let me know.

To use it:
1. Open Mail and select the tab you want to lock.
2. Close Mail.
3. Copy the .mailbundle file to `~/Library/Mail/Bundles`.
4. Reopen Mail. The header *should* now reject clicks.
5. To uninstall, remove `~/Library/Mail/Bundles/MailHeaderLock.mailbundle` and restart Mail (and to change the tab, move the plugin to somewhere else, and follow these steps again).

Comment: No problem. Just a heads up: Mail might refuse to load the plugin if you update the computer. If this happens, follow [these steps](http://www.macworld.com/article/1155728/updatemailbundles.html) to make them work again (or just let me know and I'll update it).